# How to code elementary symmetric polynomials in R

Tags: r, function

I want to program a function in R that compute the elementary symmetric polynomials. For i=0, 1, ..., p, the i-th elementary polynomial is given by

[image]

How can I code this function in R? I've tried

```
x<-c(1,2,3,4)
crossprod(x)
# or
for (i in 1:length(x)) print(crossprod((combn(x,i))))
```

but I don't get the desired result, which is supposed to give

e0= 1

e1= 10

e2= 35

e3= 50

e4= 24

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I will edit my question and add what I've tried so far ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the product of each combination using `combn(x, k, prod)` and then sum that:

```
sympoly <- function(k, x) sum(combn(x, k, prod))

sapply(0:4, sympoly, 1:4)
## [1]  1 10 35 50 24
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is not `crossprod`, it's `combn/prod` followed by `sum`.

```
elSymPoly <- function(x){
  sapply(c(0, seq_along(x)), function(n){
    sum(apply(combn(x, n), 2, prod))
  })
}

x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
elSymPoly(x)
#[1]  1 10 35 50 24
```

Note that the function also works with an empty vector (but not with `NULL`).

```
y <- integer(0)
elSymPoly(y)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Nice solution too! Yes, I was taking `crossprod`wrongly!

Comment: @coolsv Like in the answer by Gabor Grothendieck, you can simply do `sum(combn(x, n, prod))` in the `sapply` loop. I had forgotten that `combn` accepts an extra argument, a function to be applied to each combination.